# Eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, statistical-mechanics, hamiltonian, eigenvalue

Is every eigenvalue of the Hamiltonian a form of energy?
If not are there values of the Hamiltonian that do not correspond to the energy of the system?

Comment: The Hamiltonian operator is the energy operator of the quantum system. Its eigenvalues are the energy eigenvalues of the system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The physical interpretation of the eigenvalues of $H$ is that they are the *possible* outcomes of measuring the energy of your system.  The eigenvalues obviously have units of energy.